# Phenomena between ill-conditioned and well-condtioned

Tags: matrix, numerical-value

Given that I have the following sparse matrix:

```
matRules = {
  {1, 1} -> 0.664319, {1, 2} -> 0.335681, 
  {2, 2} -> 0.641645, {2, 3} -> 0.358355, 
  {3, 3} -> 0.584765, {3, 4} -> 0.415235, 
  {4, 4} -> 0.578972, {4, 5} -> 0.421028, 
  {5, 5} -> 0.575463, {5, 6} -> 0.424537, 
  {6, 6} -> 0.191367, {6, 7} -> 0.808633, 
  {7, 7} -> 0.704785, {7, 8} -> 0.295215, 
  {8, 8} -> 0.452249, {8, 9} -> 0.547751, 
  {9, 9} -> 0.558791, {9, 10} -> 0.441209, 
  {10, 10} -> 0.521902, {10, 11} -> 0.478098, 
  {11, 11} -> 0.441059, {11, 12} -> 0.558941, 
  {12, 12} -> 0.452071, {12, 13} -> 0.547929, 
  {13, 13} -> 0.402421, {13, 14} -> 0.597579, 
  {14, 1} -> 0.724525, {14, 14} -> 0.275475, {_, _} -> 0};

sparseMat = SparseArray[matRules]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 0.664319 & 0.335681 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.641645 & 0.358355 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.584765 & 0.415235 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.578972 & 0.421028 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.575463 & 0.424537 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.191367 & 0.808633 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.704785 & 0.295215 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.452249 & 0.547751 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.558791 & 0.441209 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.521902 & 0.478098 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.441059 & 0.558941 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.452071 & 0.547929 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.402421 & 0.597579 \\
 0.724525 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.275475 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then I calculate the condition number of `norm-2` and `norm-infinity` as follows:

```
condInf[mat_] := LUDecomposition[mat][[-1]]
cond2[mat_] := Max[#] / Min[#] &[SingularValueList[mat, Tolerance -> 0]]
```

That is,

```
condInf@sparseMat
(* 1.01157*10^8 *)

cond2@sparseMat
(* 6.88491*10^7 *)
```

So this matrix is ill-conditioned. However, when I remove the element `{14, 1}`, the matrix is well-conditioned.

```
matRules1 = {
  {1, 1} -> 0.664319, {1, 2} -> 0.335681, 
  {2, 2} -> 0.641645, {2, 3} -> 0.358355, 
  {3, 3} -> 0.584765, {3, 4} -> 0.415235, 
  {4, 4} -> 0.578972, {4, 5} -> 0.421028, 
  {5, 5} -> 0.575463, {5, 6} -> 0.424537, 
  {6, 6} -> 0.191367, {6, 7} -> 0.808633, 
  {7, 7} -> 0.704785, {7, 8} -> 0.295215, 
  {8, 8} -> 0.452249, {8, 9} -> 0.547751, 
  {9, 9} -> 0.558791, {9, 10} -> 0.441209, 
  {10, 10} -> 0.521902, {10, 11} -> 0.478098, 
  {11, 11} -> 0.441059, {11, 12} -> 0.558941, 
  {12, 12} -> 0.452071, {12, 13} -> 0.547929, 
  {13, 13} -> 0.402421, {13, 14} -> 0.597579, 
  (*{14, 1} -> 0.724525,*) {14, 14} -> 0.275475, {_, _} -> 0};

sparseMat1 = SparseArray[matRules1]

condInf@sparseMat1
(* 48.8335 *)

cond2@sparseMat1
(* 35.7228 *)
```

Could someone explain this phenomenon in the numerical method? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a more elementary example:

```
n = 5;
A = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1, {n, 1} -> -1}, {n, n}];
B = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1}, {n, n}];

1./Divide @@ MinMax[Diagonal[SingularValueDecomposition[A][[2]]]]
1./Divide @@ MinMax[Diagonal[SingularValueDecomposition[B][[2]]]]
```

> ComplexInfinity

> 6.74204

`A` is ill-conditioned because it is circular, hence it has the constant vectors in its null space. Thus at least one singular value must be equal to $0$. By removing the entry in the lower left corner, the matrix becomes upper triangular with $1$ on the main diagonal, hence invertible. So all singular values must be greater than $0$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Henrik :)

Comment: Your welcome, Lavender!